# Handling multiple sessions in PHP

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have a simple web site with many PHP pages. Among them, some four pages use common variables, which I should store in the session object. But the thing is, these values should not be visible to other pages, so I decided to use `session_name` to create a new session. It will start a new session but these four pages are using the values from the old session, which is creating a problem when I try to print `$_SESSION`: it is an empty array after the start of my new session. I want this new session to retain the old values plus new values.

I'm not looking for this `$_SESSION['page_group']['variable_name']` kind of solution as I cannot use arrays.

Comment: Welcome! I don't understand; why can't the other *pages* "see" the session variables? "Multiple initialized sessions per page" sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Sounds like several web-apps on one server.

Comment: @JaredFarrish thanks,bcoz i need all these variables which i created in these four pages to be unset on particular check how many variables i created what variables i created i really dont have control over them using other session i can unset all the variables in that session by simply destroying the new session

Comment: I take it storing it in a table in a database by the session ID, checking the URL for the "right" page, and setting whatever variables from the table, isn't possible? (Which you should also purge of expired sessions.)

Comment: @JaredFarrish  that's a possible solution, but is it not possible the way which i told what are possible difficulties if i try to do it that way? i.e., using two sessions sorry if i'm asking to basics i'm really new to multiple sessions concept.

Comment: @PLB there is no apps involved

Answer (score 1):

How about using something like

```
session_start();
$temp=$_SESSION;
session_write_close();
session_name("newname");
session_start();
```

and then merge $temp into (the new) $_SESSION (where needed)?

Comment: I have tried the above mentioned code but there is a problem.If i'm trying to print $_SESSION after the new session_start before merging with $temp still i'm getting the values which are set for earlier sessions.